# Cleanup Code for UserControl as Content of TabItem on removal from TabControl

Tags: .net, wpf, tabcontrol, dispose, dispatcher

I have a WPF `UserControl` that is added as `Content` in a `TabItem`. The `TabItem` is added to the `Items` collection of `TabControl`. The `Header` of the `TabItem` contains one `Label` and one `Button`. The button click removes the TabItem from the Items collection of TabControl. So the reference of UserControl is not there anymore. I have some clean up code to be run for the UserControl when the TabItem is removed.

I was looking for `Dispose` method in the UserControl, but there is no such method available for overriding.

Also, I tried to use `Dispatcher.ShutdownStarted` Event, but that also doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You could extend `UserControl` and add a method to clean up your control. You can call this method from where ever you remove the `TabItem` from the `TabControl` from:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ExtendedUserControl control = (ExtendedUserControl)tabItem.Content;
    control.CleanUp();
    tabControl.Items.Remove(tabItem);
}
```

Alternatively, you could add the clean up method to your data class that is data bound to the `UserControl`:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    UserControl control = (UserControl)tabItem.Content;
    YourDataClass data = (YourDataClass)control.DataContext;
    data.CleanUp();
    tabControl.Items.Remove(tabItem);
}
```